# Why is my Point array only returning null in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, null, return, point

I'm trying to write a method that uses a board and check to see if at any given point on the board, a swap between one point to right or below, causes a "match" to occur on the board. The points that cause the swap are then added to a Point[] and returned. My array returns, but it only returns, [null],[null],[null]. Why is it not returning points?

Thanks

```
public static Point[] findPossibleSwaps(Board b) 
{
    Point[] swaps = new Point[3];
    int x = 0; 
    int y = 0;

    Point normal = new Point (x,y); 
    Point hor = new Point (x+1, y);
    Point ver = new Point (x, y+1);
    int count = 0;
    for(y = 0; y < b.getSize()-1; y++)
    {
        for(x = 0; x < b.getSize()-1; x++)
        {
            b.swapSquares(normal,hor);
            if (b.hasMatches() && (x)!=b.getSize()-1) 
            {
                swaps[count] = new Point(x+1,y);   
                count++;
            }
            b.swapSquares(hor, normal);
            b.swapSquares(normal, ver);
            if (b.hasMatches() && y!=b.getSize()-1)
            {
                swaps[count] = new Point(x,y+1);                                 
                count++;
            }
            b.swapSquares(ver, normal); 
        }

    }   
return swaps;
}
```

Comment: You only add `Point`s to your swaps array if `b.hasMatches() && (x) != b.getSize() - 1` or if `b.hasMatches() && y != b.getSize() - 1`.  I would assume that since your array is empty, those statements never evaluate to true.  Without knowing what `b.hasMatches()` does, or what the state of the board is, it's impossible to know why, though.

Comment: as azurefrog said, I would try debugging this line for line! also what I find weird: arent your loops stop one step too early? it should either be x < b.size() or x <= b.size()-1, but not the combination of both

Comment: Thanks so far everyone! b.hasMatches will return 'true' if, as a result of the swap, a "match" is created on the board. A match is just three or more consecutive items of the same type. In this game they are colors. It will return false if no matches are created as a result of the swap.

Comment: Then the reason your swap array is empty is that there are no matches on the board.

Comment: That's odd - i have a method that tests the board, and it returns six points -- ill check out the hasMatches method for error